# Comparing Two Char [in C]

Tags: c, char, compare

I have a struct

```
struct Human {
    char            *name;
    struct location *location;
    int             cash;
    char            *weapon;

};
```

and another one:

```
struct World {
    char                *name;
    char                *weapon;
    int                 price;
};
```

These are in header files, and included in a .c program.

**Question**

I want to compare if the weapon is the same as in both locations

**What I tried**

```
int compareWeapons(struct bot *b,int whatToGet) // function signature
struct location *l =  b->location;
if ((strcmp(l->weapon,b->weapon) == 0)) { // do stuff }
```

** Error message I get **

> runtime error: load of null pointer of type 'char'

Kindly advise me, how do I compare two char in different struct, if not using strcmp??

Comment: Your stuct location really has field char* weapon?

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is not the strcmp but the null pointer which means that the variable "**b**"==NULL,so "**b**" has no "**location**" attribute and that's where the **NullPointerException** generates.
I may suggest to check how you pass the arguments to your function
Use **&** to pass the address (pointer) of your variable or just the name of your variable if it's a pointer
Also I didn't understand the type "**bot**" and "**location**"
I think you meant "**struct Human**" not "**struct bot**" and "**struct World**" not "**struct location**"
You can name your struct so you don't have to write struct at each declaration

```
struct World{
//variables
}World;
```

And then **struct World** would be the same as just saying **World**

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not your string compare, it's how you are declaring your structs.

It seems you are using (struct bot *) to reference the (struct Human).
In that case it should look:

```
int compareWeapons(struct World *b, int whattoget);
```

Additionally your struct location must be initialized or else you are referencing a struct that contains nothing (NULL).

```
struct location
{
    //your struct variables
};
```

Below is a link with a basic example on how to initialize a struct, https://www.cs.usfca.edu/~wolber/SoftwareDev/C/CStructs.htm